# How to faster way of implementing interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I have one interface and there will be a lot of implementations of it. I wonder is there any fast way to do it (without using ctrl+v).

If I highlight the name of interface and click create new class then the name is copied as name of a new class.

Is there any way to make a new class implement always the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use some IDE, like Eclipse or IntelliJ ? Then you could create a template that already contains all the boilerplate code, including the interface declaration.

All you would have to do is create a class, replace its default content with the template, and fill in the blanks.

I don't see any practical means to do otherwise without resorting to writing some shell/ant script.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say create a simple implementation with default methods then copy-paste it. When you paste it into the same package you'll be asked to rename the file and thus the class as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just how many implementations counts as "a lot"?

Consider the time taken to type "implements" and then enough of the interface name to let content assist fill in the rest, then hit Ctrl-1 and get Eclipse to fill in the stub methods.

If that time is a really significant portion of the time taken to write and thoroughly test these implementations, have you considered an alternative design which *doesn't* require so many implementations?

Comment: I have Filter interface(that filters text base on many rules) and a lot(now 6, but there will be more) of implementations of it. what alternative design do you propose?

Comment: @IAdapter: If there are many rules, do you really think that the time spent creating the class will be significant compared with implementation and testing? It feels like you're focusing on something which isn't actually going to take you long.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you modify the file template so that it contains the interface name you want, e.g. "implements IAdapter"?

Apologies for not being more precise, but I've not worked with Eclipse in a long time and forgot lots of things about it (such as how file templates look).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know is when you select `New -> Class` and then you can select the interface(s) to implement. The first time you need to click `Add` and search for the interface, but for subsequent class creations you will see that interface in the list automatically and you can then just select it every time.